# Access Form UI for One to One relationships. Don't want to cascade delete

Tags: ms-access

Working on an Access Database to manage a race.  Racers need to be members of an organization to race.  They can be existing members, or sign up to be members of the organization on race day.  Racers sometimes enter, then scratch from the race between registration and the race...in this case, we want the entry removed from the racer table.

I have a table of Members that includes: MemberID, Name, Address.  This is pre-populated from another database.  Basically a download of all the members.
I have a table of Racers that includes: MemberID, Bib#, Class
This is a one to one relationship.  You cannot have a racer enter the race multiple times.

I want to be able to, IN ONE CONTINUOUS FORM:
1. Create race entries, on a form, by typing in the MemberID, Bib# and Class, but have the name from Members shown in the form after the MemberID is entered.
2. Allow deletion of a MemberID in the racer table, but not delete the entry in the member table.
3. Allow entry of a new MemberID (when they register they can become members) and associated name and address along with the Bib# and Class and have the MemberID, Bib# and Class update Racers and MemberID, Name and Address Update Members.  Additional requirement that the Member table has an entry with the memberID...I don't want to force validation of the memberid in the racer table against the memberid in the member table.

I have tried using just a lookup in the table for the member#.  This cascade deletes the member entry.

I have tried using a 1:1 relationship, same thing.

Tried form and subform, but isn't allowed on continuous form.

I can code VBA, and am skilled enough to write code for data validation or manipulation based on event data.  I just need some direction on how I can accomplish this...

Comment: Don't delete records, have a Status field and flag entrant as "Withdrawn", apply filter to exclude from queries.

Comment: Why would a lookup delete a record? Need to show code. If you don't want to enforce referential integrity then why have this set in relationship? Even so, deleting a racer should not delete member. Racer table should be the dependent dataset. Something is wrong with relationship setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want form/subform arrangement then use a form bound to Racers with a combobox to select member.

1. Use a multi-column combobox that includes member name field in RowSource query. Then a textbox can reference the combobox column to display member name: `=cbxMember.Column(1)`
2. Racers table should be dependent and deleting record should not cause member record to delete - something is wrong with relationship settings.
3. Use combobox NotInList event to create new member records 'on-the-fly' during racer data entry.

Or use a technique to synchronize two related subforms https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp
In summary:

> Create an intermediate text box on the main form for the LinkMaster
>   value. This references the current record in the master subform, then
>   the detail subform can link to that value. By making this control
>   invisible, your users won't see this link.   To reference a value in a
>   subform, use the following syntax for the text box's Control Source
>   property:   `=[subFormName].[Form]![ControlName]`   where subFormName
>   is the name of your master subform control, and ControlName is the
>   name of your control that the detail records are filtered.   In the
>   sample database, this becomes:   `=[subMaster].[Form]![txtID]`   Now
>   that the master value is exposed, we call this control 'txtMasterID'
>   and use it as the Link Master Field for the second subform.   It's
>   good to keep this text box visible while you design and test the form.
>   Once it's working, set its Visible property to No so your users don't
>   see the magic you've created!

Comment: 1 worked perfectly!  
2 I played with the relationship and think I got it right.  Not deleting now.  
3 Led me in the right direction, found this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.notinlist  Gave me the code I needed to enter a new member entry and requery racer entry!

Thank you for the help!!!!!!!!